# Identical jsons but different disk sizes

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a python script agregating data stored in several csv files. After agregating the data, I export it using

```
 pd.json("myfile.json", orient="table")
```

This is done locally on my Windows 10 computer.

I use the same code and functions with the same data on AWS Lambda, by reading the data from an S3 bucket. I downloaded the exported json file, and load them both with pandas.

Using

```
myLocaljson.equals(myAwsjson)
```

I verified that they are indeed equal. The dtypes are also equal. But the disks sizes are different. One is 259 KB and the other is 267 KB.

Do you have ideas why?

Comment: that's usual if you run on 2 different systems (OSes), file sizes maybe be different when the default cluster sizes are different (windows default cluster size: 4k)

Comment: You may check page size on your machine and S3. ```getconf PAGE_SIZE```

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably caused by the whitespace characters.

Windows has the line endings `\r\n`, most other OSes only use `\n`. So that's one extra character per line.

Also, this JSON file:

```json
{"foo":"bar","baz":[]}
```

is equal to this one:

```json
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": [
    ]
}
```

which is actually a nice representation of this:

```json
{\n\t"foo": "bar",\n\t"baz": [\n\t]\n}
```

So JSON objects can be "equal", although the string representing them can be very different.

Comment: Unfortunately, I checked the strings and they are the same as well, since they were both created using the pd.to_json function.

Comment: How exactly are you comparing the strings? If you are loading the files in python or using a text editor, that is a step that can "hide" the difference or even remove it while loading the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess non-printable characters at the end of the File,  open it with a HEX editor and compare the file.

The other option is the was small files are stored on a hard disk, 1024 - 1KB files will not take up 1024KB of disk space but take up significantly more disk space depending on the cluster size of the drive.